# Footnotes in tabular environments within multicols

Tags: tables, footnotes, multicol

I'm running into a strange inconsistency when I use footnotes in and out of tabular environments within multicols.  In particular, I'm declaring a savenotes environment in a style file as follows:

```
\makesavenoteenv[tabunote]{tabular}
```

Then, in the same two-column page of my document, I'm using a footnote from within a `tabunote` environment

[image]

and another footnote in a bare paragraph

[image]

producing the following results:

[image]

It appears that my first footnote, from within the savenotes tabular environment, wraps to the column, whereas the bare footnote wraps to the page (which is the behavior I expect under `multicols`).  Moreover, since the `savenotes` footnote comes first, it causes the footnote separator line to be half the expected length—on pages where I reverse the order of footnotes (bare, then `tabunote`), the separator is normal-length.  The following should yield similar results:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{footnote}
\usepackage{multicols}

\makesavenoteenv[tabunote]{tabular}

\begin{document}
\begin{multicols}{2}

\begin{center}
  \begin{tabunote}{c|c}
    foo & bar%
    \footnote{A long enough footnote here will wrap to the column
    rather than to the page---this is easily illustrated by the use
    of lots of filler text.}
  \end{tabunote}
\end{center}

On the other hand, this footnote will be fine.%
\footnote{Here is the aforementioned example of the footnote that is
fine and represents the expected behavior for footnotes in a multicols
environment.}

\end{multicols}
\end{document}
```

Is there a way to rectify this issue?  In particular, how can I use both bare and tabular/`savenotes` footnotes such that both wrap to the page, rather than the column?

Comment: Could you please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem? It will be much easier for us to find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Sure thing—updated.

Comment: An easy way out would be to use the usual `\footnotemark`/`\footnotetext` approach. Then you could also drop the `footnotes` package and use the normal `{tabular}` environment.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add the following code to the preamble:

```
\makeatletter
\def\savenotes{%
  \begingroup%
  \if@savingnotes\else%
    \@savingnotestrue%
    \let\@footnotetext\fn@fntext%
    \let\@mpfootnotetext\fn@fntext%
    \fn@width\textwidth%
    \let\fn@colwidth\fn@width%
    \global\setbox\fn@notes\box\voidb@x%
    \let\fn@thempfn\thempfn%
    \let\fn@mpfn\@mpfn%
    \ifx\@minipagerestore\relax\let\@minipagerestore\@empty\fi%
    \expandafter\def\expandafter\@minipagerestore\expandafter{%
      \@minipagerestore%
      \let\thempfn\fn@thempfn%
      \let\@mpfn\fn@mpfn%
    }%
  \fi%
}
\makeatother
```

and the footnote inside your custom tabular environment will have the right width. 
[image]

I think that when the environment for which the footnotes are stored (the `tabunote` in your case) is placed inside a `multicol` env. the `fn@width` is not set to the `textwidth` but stays at the default value, which is `columnwidth`. In the code above the default value has been changed to `textwidth`. The line I changed is

```
\fn@width\textwidth
```

which was originally

```
 \fn@width\columnwidth
```

This way the width is not wrapped around the column.

The reasons why the default `fn@width` is set to `columnwidth` are explained in the `footnote` documentation at page 4.

I'm not sure if there are cases where the change in the default value will cause problems, but I assume that if there are someone will tell us :)

Comment: the same a bit shorter: `\usepackage{etoolbox}\patchcmd\savenotes{\columnwidth}{\textwidth}{}{}` :)

Comment: @cgnieder cool, thanks! I think it's time to look at the etoolbox package doc. :)

Comment: And I would consider this a bug in the `footnotes` package from `mdwtools` bundle: It should have used `\linewidth`, I guess.