# How to make Tufte sidenotes behave properly in tcolorbox environments?

Tags: footnotes, margins, tcolorbox, tufte, sidenotes

Marginnotes (sidenotes), and therefore citations in the tufte-book class don't play nice with the theorem boxes in tcolorbox. I've tried to rewrite the citation and marginnote commands in tufte using a macro that detects the current environment ([Relevant](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39738/command-behavior-depending-on-current-environment) [Links](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18652/how-can-i-check-if-the-current-code-is-inside-a-certain-environment) [Here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/512495/sidenotes-and-marginfigures-in-tcolorbox-theorems)) but I haven't been able to make it work.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[justified, nofonts, notitlepage, openany, debug]{tufte-book}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\tcbuselibrary{skins}
\tcbuselibrary{breakable}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}
\newtcbtheorem{theorem}{Theorem}{parbox=false, breakable, sharp corners, skin=enhanced, frame hidden, colback=white, coltitle=white, colbacktitle=black, adjusted title, fonttitle=\bfseries}{th}

\def\bibsection{~\\ \section*{\refname}}
\begin{document}

\begin{theorem}{Pythagoras\cite{kontsevich-manin}}
    $$a^2 + b^2 = c^2$$\marginnote{Lorem ipsum et cetera}
\end{theorem}
\marginnote{Regular marginnote}
Here's a regular citation to illustrate expected behavior:\cite{witten}

\begin{theorem}{\marginnote{The quick brown fox or something}}
    $$d^2 + e^2 = f^2$$\cite{hartshorne}
\end{theorem}

\bibliographystyle{plainnat}
\bibliography{sample}
\end{document}
```

Above code produces the following:
[image: Broken LaTeX]

Expected (desired) behavior is for citations to print to a marginnote outside of the tcolorbox, and to maintain numbering with the rest of the document.

Edit: I attempted fixes in the vein of [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/402930/sidenote-in-mdframed-environment-tufte-latex) question, to save the sidenotes from a theorem environment and place them after the end of the environment, but was unable to get it working. Another strategy is to redefine \cite and \marginnote to behave one way if not inside a theorem box, and to behave differently if inside the theorem box.

Comment: a) `\newtcbtheorem` defines a theorem env accepting _two_, not one mandatory arguments. So you should use `\begin{theorem}{<title>}{<label, possibly empty>}`. b) Both `\marginnote` and `\footnote` in tufte create floats, which cannot be used in any box (here `theorem` env), see https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/208662.

Comment: @muzimuzhiZ it seems that there are workarounds for footnotes (see https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/111638/footnotes-in-tabular-environments-within-multicols, or the above link detailing the \savenotes \spewnotes trick from etoolbox). In the situations where these solutions work, are footnotes not floats?

Comment: In ordinary document classes, `\footnote` is not a float. It is `tufte` that redefines `\footnote` to be typeset as a sidenote, which internally uses `\marginpar` and is a float.

Comment: https://github.com/T-F-S/tcolorbox/issues/192